# What is the difference between NaN and Inf, and NULL and NA in R?

Tags: r

What is the difference between NaN and Inf, and NULL and NA in R?

Why `?NA` and `?NULL` tell me that "NA" has a length of "1" whereas NULL has a length of "0"?

Comment: NaN vs Inf is pretty consistent across all computer languages (and standard math definitions, too) . 0/0 is one example of NaN, and 1/0 is one example of Inf.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In R language, there are two closely related null-like values: `NA` and `NULL`. Both are used to represent missing or undefined values.

**`NULL`** represents the null object, it's a reserved word.
`NULL` is perhaps returned by expressions and functions, so that values are undefined.

**`NA`** is a logical constant of length 1, which contains a missing value indicator. `NA` can be freely coerced to any other vector type except raw.
There are also constants `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_` and `NA_character_` of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd also recommend reading http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/.

Comment: Even if `-0` returns `0`, it seems to be that `1/0` returns `Inf` but `1/-0` returns `-Inf`.

Answer (score 46):

In short

```
NaN  : means 0/0 -- Stands for Not a Number
NA   : is generally interpreted as a missing, does not exist or undefined
NULL : is for empty object.
```

For an exact definition, you can read the documentation, which is very well written.

Comment: This answer contains at least two incorrect statements. Yes, `0/0` returns `NaN` but so does, e.g., `log(-1)`. Thus `NaN` does not mean `0/0`. It rather means "undefined" (in the mathematical sense). `NA` does not mean "does not exist". It rather means "unknown".