# Dplyr produces NaN while base R produces NA

Tags: r, dplyr, nan, na

Consider the following toy data and computations:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-  tibble(x = 1)

stats::sd(df$x)

dplyr::summarise(df, sd_x = sd(x))
```

The first calculation results in `NA` whereas the second, when the calculation is included in the dplyr function `summarise` produces `NaN`. I would expect both calculations to generate the same result and I wonder why they differ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between NaN and Inf, and NULL and NA in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496361/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-inf-and-null-and-na-in-r)

Comment: I can duplicate. dplyr version 0.7.4 - the latest version from CRAN.

Comment: Same here. However, what do you need that for? If you ask `is.na()`, both return a `TRUE`.

Comment: Interesting. For me both result with NA: `> stats::sd(df$x) 
[1] NA` and `> dplyr::summarise(df, sd_x = sd(x)) 
# A tibble: 1 x 1 
   sd_x 
  <dbl> 
1    NA`

Comment: @storaged What version of `dplyr` are you using?

Comment: @JohnPaul dplyr version 0.7.4

Comment: I'm the OP and I'm also using dplyr version 0.7.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is calling a different function. I'm not clear what the function is, but it is not the `stats` one.

```
dplyr::summarise(df, sd_x = stats::sd(x))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   sd_x
  <dbl>
1    NA

debugonce(sd) # debug to see when sd is called
```

Not called here:

```
dplyr::summarise(df, sd_x = sd(x))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   sd_x
  <dbl>
1   NaN
```

But called here:

```
dplyr::summarise(df, sd_x = stats::sd(x))
debugging in: stats::sd(1)
debug: sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
    na.rm = na.rm))
...
```

*Update*

It appears that the `sd` within `summarise` gets calculated outside of R, hinted at in this header file: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/inst/include/dplyr/Result/Sd.h

A number of functions seem to be redefined by dplyr. Given that `var` gives the same result in both cases, I think the sd behaviour is a bug.

Comment: what is you R dplyr and R version? I am surprised that I cannot reproduce the bug...

Comment: I also get `NA` when I do `dplyr::mutate(df, var_x = var(x))`. I've accepted this answer based on the suggestion that the behavior is a bug.