# Why do we omit NULL values instead of replacing by 0 in a vector?

Tags: r, null

I have a dataset of characters including `NULL` values as `"NA"`. To calculate the mean value should I omit NA or replace NA with 0?

Someone encouraged me to omit `NULL` values rather replace with 0.My question is why we shouldn't replace with 0?

```
OmitNA<-na.omit(oswego$age) # The NA value is omitted and remaining data is stored in OmitNA
AsNum<-as.numeric(OmitNA) # OmitNA from previous step is stored as numberic in AsNum
print(mean(AsNum)) # Mean is calculated
```

I need a reason why I shouldn't replace `NULL` with 0.

Comment: Because it can affect the `mean` `v1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 0);
v2 <- c(1, 2, 2, NA);mean(v1)
[1] 1.25
> mean(v2, na.rm = TRUE)#
[1] 1.666667`  In the second case, `NA` element is removed from calculating `sum(na.omit(v2))/length(na.omit(v2))#
[1] 1.666667`

Comment: It's worth mentioning than `NULL` and `NA` are [two different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496361/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-inf-and-null-and-na-in-r).