# Data returning is.null() as False even though my data has NA in it?

Tags: r, dataframe, null

I am running an `is.null()` on the columns in my dataset and it returns False even though I can see NA values in my dataset. Is there a better function in R to check for null rows/entries in a column?

Comment: to check for `NA` values use `is.na`, Eg - `is.na(df$column_name)` or `is.na(df)` where `df` is the dataframe.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496361/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-inf-and-null-and-na-in-r

Comment: @RonakShah `is.na()` is working but it's printing row-wise results. Is there a way to aggregate them for the whole column or the whole data frame?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Do you need `colSums(is.na(df))` ? This will count number of `NA` values in each column.

Comment: @RonakShah yes, I used the sum function `sum(is.na(data$col))`. I am moving from Python to R and in Python which have functions that return a boolean value `True` if the column even has one empty value but R doesn't have something inbuilt like that but yeah it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `help("anyNA")`

Comment: For the sake of completeness, R has the `any()` function which tests if at least one element of a logical vector is TRUE. (BTW, `all()` tests if all elements are TRUE), So, `any(is.na())` should do what are asking for. However, `anyNA()` is shorter.