# R: Ho to convert `"NULL"` into `NULL`?

Tags: r, string, null, type-conversion

How do you convert a string that says NULL (`"NULL"`) into an actual `NULL` value in R?

I am getting an envvar that contains either a string or `"NULL"` (also a string) and my R code is looking for either a string or `NULL`. This looks so simple but for example `stringr::str_replace_all("test", 'NULL', NULL)` does not work:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all("test", 'NULL', NULL)
Error in `stringr::str_replace_all()`:
! `replacement` must be a character vector, not `NULL`.
```

Comment: I expect you want `NA_character_` here, not `NULL`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15496361/6851825

Comment: To convert into an actual `NULL` will remove that element from the vector. Can you settle for `NA`?

Comment: Or perhaps `a <- "NULL"; if(a == "NULL") NULL else a`?

Comment: @JonSpring the if/else solution is the direction i am going in right now. If it works out fine ill post an answer to this question.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't want `NULL`, which can't be part of a character vector. You want `NA`, which indicates missing values in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it going with a simpler if/else:

```
fun(
base.url = if (Sys.getenv('BASE_URL') == 'NULL') {as.null()} else {Sys.getenv('BASE_URL')}, ...) {
...
}
```